# Pulling Data From Sharepoint List with Infopath 2013

Tags: infopath, sharepoint-online

I'm trying to get an InfoPath 2013 form to interact with a SharePoint list which has 6 columns currently:

```
 ID   upc   name   cost   price
```

I am working on a basic InfoPath form with the following intention:

- The user types in a number in the "upc" field
- The "name" "cost" and "price" fields are populated with the information associated with the "upc" on my Sharepoint list.

I've looked everywhere and nothing is working out. This is the simplest solution I've found and nothing works:

- Started a new InfoPath form
- Went to the Data tab and added a data connection "From SharePoint List" - the list name is "simpletest" - and selected the fields I'd be using
- Added two textbox fields to the form (field1 and field2)
- Created a rule on field2 on the condition that "field1" "is equal to" "upc" (selected from the datafields portion of the "simpletest" connection) to perform an action "set a field's value" "field2" = "price" (selected from the datafields portion of the "simpletest" connection)

From what I can tell, this is correct. But it doesn't work. Does anyone see the holes in my methodology here? It seems pretty straightforward, so I don't know where I'm going wrong.

Comment: Are you sure that you are calling the action Query for Data? Remember that you need to query sharepoint for the data

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is you're not querying the data.

You either need to go back in the data connection and check the box that reads query data automatically or write a rule or make a button that calls the query if the data is changed or the button is pressed.

Hope that Helps